# Box left aligned

Tags: alignment, framed

I use in my manuskript two latex constructs to draw a frame around a text which I would need left aligned **without changing `\parindent`** before and after the box. But both of them are printed at the position of `\parindent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\parindent=7mm
\newenvironment{rfbox}{\begin{minipage}{8.0cm}}{\end{minipage}}
\newcommand{\ffbox}[1]{\vspace{0.0cm}{\fbox{\begin{rfbox} #1 \end{rfbox}}}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\\

\noindent This is left aligned.\\

\fbox{%
\parbox{8cm}{%
\noindent The box around this should be left aligned.

}}\\

\noindent This is also left aligned.\\

\ffbox{
The box around this should also be left aligned.

}\\

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: erh  `\noindent\fbox{...}`, you are starting a new paragraph before your box.

Comment: @hjele You shouldn't abuse \\ for line breaks

Comment: @daleif thats it. Thx. Did not know where to put the \noindent

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the question, but with `tcolorbox` is easy to produce left aligned boxes because it's the default behaviour.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside, toc=listofnumbered, headinclude, 
      footinclude, index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\parindent=7mm
%\newenvironment{rfbox}{\begin{minipage}{8.0cm}}{\end{minipage}}
%\newcommand{\ffbox}[1]{\vspace{0.0cm}{\fbox{\begin{rfbox} #1 \end{rfbox}}}}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    sharp corners, colback=white, boxsep=0mm, boxrule=1pt, #1
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\noindent This is left aligned.

\begin{mybox}[width=8cm]
This is also left aligned
\end{mybox}

\noindent This is also left aligned.

\begin{mybox}[width=8cm]
The box around this should also be left aligned.
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @daleif said, you can use `\noindent` before `\fbox`, but the package `framed` makes your work more simpler, and the `MWE` is:

```
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{framed}
...
\end{framed}
```

Comment: Isn't `framed` a bit antique nowadays? If we're playing with boxes I'd go full `tcolorbox`

Comment: @daleif Yes, I agree with you